# Set proxy authentication information in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I wish to use Fiddler to debug the submitted request/responses from my SOAP client. I am inside a network that needs proxy authentication to talk to the server outside the network. Fiddler2 provides option to set the upstream proxy, but without the authentication information. How can I set it?

Comment: So, how did you do this? Which beta of fiddler did you use and how could you set the credentials? It would be helpfull to others to share this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Fiddler2. The new BETA version has got the feature of putting the proxy credentials.

Comment: So, how did you do this? Which beta of fiddler did you use and how could you set the credentials? It would be helpfull to others to share this information

Comment: -1. Whoopee. That's not an answer. How did you do it?

Comment: @CADbloke: Seems you are in haste to downvote. It is always better to see documentation. See: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp

Comment: No, he is not in a hurry.  The answer should be in your answer, not in a link, which now is dead.